# Python suds_passworddigest module : "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UsernameDigestToken'"

Tags: python, suds

I have following python code :

```
    import suds
    import os
    import suds_passworddigest

    SERVER_URL = 'http://<address>/onvif/device_service'
    WSDL_URL='file:' + os.getcwd() + '/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl'
    cli=suds.client.Client(WSDL_URL)
    cli.set_options(location=SERVER_URL)
    security =  suds.wsse.Security()
    token = suds_passworddigest.UsernameDigestToken('usr', 'password')  
    #token.setnonce(token.setonce()) # token.setonce() didn't work for me

    security.tokens.append(token)
    cli.set_options(wsse=security)

    list_of_methods = [method for method in cli.wsdl.services[0].ports[0].methods]  
    print list_of_methods
    res=cli.service.GetDNS()
    print res
```

it gives the

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UsernameDigestToken'

i checked my imports and look at the source code of **[suds-passworddigest](https://github.com/suvit/suds-passworddigest)** it has attribute `UsernameDigestToken` so why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below. UsernameDigestToken is an attribute of token.py

```
from suds_passworddigest.token import UsernameDigestToken
...
...
...
token = UsernameDigestToken('usr', 'password')
```